# Visual 2013 Plugin to record how long you've been working on a project.

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012

Hey I'm new to C++ and Visual Studio, I was wondering if there was a plugin I could find perhaps through MSDN or elsewhere that recorded how many hours have been spent on a project (aka had Visual open with the solution open). If this does not exist is this something that could very easily be developed or does it require to be developed through Visual and licensed and such before usage? I.E. Could I and some classmates work on developing something like this just using an open source project?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's [Codealike](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/4cd5e9ff-d183-46e0-9934-c8832924abb7) (from the extension page):

> Isn't it curious that you have clocks everywhere but you cannot tell
>   exactly how much time you spend coding? That won't happen to you
>   anymore, Codealike will show you the amount of time when coding,
>   debugging, building...

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [Visual Time Spent](http://vlasovstudio.com/visual-time-spent/) plugin (developed by me, 30-day trial) to track how long you've been working on a solution, project and file/window.

Comment: I downloaded Codealike because it's free and has a premium version which I'm not interested in yet. I may take a look at yours in the future if I still haven't found what I'm looking for, I'd suggest a free version!